# Definitive integral difference vs Sum of iteration

Tags: integration, summation

I wanted to calculate heat (change of Enthalpy) required for one mole of Nitrogen to increase the temperature from 90°C (363K) to 800°(1073K). But I have encountered a quite big difference between the two methods of calculating (3,644 Joule). Why there is such is large difference?

$$\delta H=\int_{T1}^{T2} Cp dt $$
I have have used equation and describing Heat capacity Cp from [NIST pages](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7727379&Type=JANAFG&Plot=on)

$$C_p° = A + B*t + C*t^2 + D*t^3 + \frac{E}{t^2} $$

*Where I have noted that Temperature is in Kelvin divided by 1000 **K/1000***  
***Method 1 - Using integration*** 
I have integrated the equation from NIST to get Enthalpy like below:
$$\int_{\frac{363}{1000}}^{\frac{1073}{1000}} = At + B\frac{t^2}{2}+C\frac{t^3}{3}+D\frac{t^4}{4}-\frac{E}{t}$$

and just because the NIST has two curves for range I needed calculation I had to split it into two integrals with different coefficients (A, B, C, D, E)
$$\int_{\frac{363}{1000}}^{\frac{500}{1000}} = At + B\frac{t^2}{2}+C\frac{t^3}{3}+D\frac{t^4}{4}-\frac{E}{t}$$
$$\int_{\frac{500}{1000}}^{\frac{1073}{1000}} = At + B\frac{t^2}{2}+C\frac{t^3}{3}+D\frac{t^4}{4}-\frac{E}{t}$$

and just because the temperature was in ***K/1000*** have multiplied the result by 1000 and as a result, I get **21,974 Joule**.

***Method 2***
just because I was not sure if I get right result I have calculated ***Cp*** (for each degree) in range 283 to 1073 Kelvin in MS Excel (again with using two ranges 100-500K and 500-2000K). Then I have summed that and get result **25,618 Joule**.
$$\delta H = \sum_{i=363}^{1073} A + B*t_i + C*t_i^2 + D*t_i^3 + \frac{E}{t_i^2} $$

Comment: Why do you expect the difference to be lower?

Comment: I have expected to be lower as those two approaches seemed to calculate the same thing. Also, 3.6kJ is not negligible, therefore I doubted my knowledge of mathematics and asked why those approached could end up with such a difference.

Comment: Shouldn't the integration range also be multiplied by 1000?

Comment: I have have actually divided the integration range by 1000 as the equation is describing T in K/1000 so integrated from 0.363 to 1.073.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you made a mistake (because of the bounds). You need to read the formulae as

$$Cp^0=a+ b \tau + c \tau^2+ d \tau^3 + \frac e {\tau^2} \qquad \text {with} \qquad \tau=\frac T{1000}$$ which implies
$$\int Cp^0\,dT=1000 a \tau +500 b \tau ^2+\frac{1000 c }{3}\tau ^3+250 d   \tau ^4-\frac{1000 e}{\tau }$$

Computing $$\int_{363}^{500} Cp^0\,dT =4020.384807 \qquad \text {and} \qquad \int_{500}^{1073} Cp^0\,dT =17952.71724$$ which make
$$\int_{363}^{1073} Cp^0\,dT =21973.10205$$ which is your result.

Now, I computed the sums with a step size equal to $10^{-k}$ degree and obtained the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k  & \Sigma_1 & \Sigma_2 & \Sigma_3 \\
 0 & 4049.768171 & 17984.05571 & 22033.82388 \\
 1 & 4023.323119 & 17955.85108 & 21979.17420 \\
 2 & 4020.678638 & 17953.03063 & 21973.70926
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

In comments, you asked for the reverse problem, that it to say, knowing $H$ and $T_1$ (the lower bound for the integration), how to compute $T_2$ (the upper bound for the integration). With the kind of formulae as usually given in *NIST Webbook*, you typically face by the end to a polynomial equation of degree $5$; since you cannot solve them, you need a numerical method and, then, a reasonable starting guess.

For that, in a preliminary step (to be done only once for a given component), assume that you can approximate the given formula by a quadratic
$$Cp^0 \sim A+B \tau+ C \tau^2$$ and the new parameters could be computed. For example, you could take ten or many more) equally spaced temperatures between  the lower and upper bounds for the correlation**s**), compute the corresponding exact values and perform a quadratic regression (trend line in Excel).

I did it for the second correlation for nitrogen $( 500 \leq T \leq 2000)$ and obtained
$$A=25.1335 \qquad B=9.67815  \qquad C= -2.13695 $$ and below is the comparison of the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \tau & \text{exact} & \text{approximation} \\
 0.5 & 29.5813 & 29.4384 \\
 0.6 & 30.1040 & 30.1711 \\
 0.7 & 30.7601 & 30.8611 \\
 0.8 & 31.4381 & 31.5084 \\
 0.9 & 32.0893 & 32.1129 \\
 1.0 & 32.6917 & 32.6747 \\
 1.1 & 33.2366 & 33.1938 \\
 1.2 & 33.7218 & 33.6701 \\
 1.3 & 34.1491 & 34.1037 \\
 1.4 & 34.5224 & 34.4945 \\
 1.5 & 34.8472 & 34.8426 \\
 1.6 & 35.1296 & 35.1480 \\
 1.7 & 35.3764 & 35.4106 \\
 1.8 & 35.5947 & 35.6305 \\
 1.9 & 35.7920 & 35.8076 \\
 2.0 & 35.9760 & 35.9420
\end{array}
\right)$$

Suppose that we integrate from $\tau=0.65$ and the result is $H=34.567$. So, we have now to solve for $\tau$ the cubic equation (easy to solve)
$$-0.712317 \tau ^3+4.83907 \tau ^2+25.1335 \tau -18.1857=34.567$$ which shows three real solutions (but two of them are outside the range). So, this gives  $\tau_0=1.687$. With this, we can start Newton method for the true formulation
$$-49.9092+19.5058 \tau +9.94352 \tau ^2-2.86618 \tau
   ^3+0.342446 \tau ^4-\frac{0.527601}{\tau }=0$$ Newton iterates will be

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \tau_n \\
 0 & 1.68700000000 \\
 1 & 1.68711265351 \\
 2 & 1.68711265309 
\end{array}
\right)$$

This was a multi step procedure based on the $C_p^0$ and I could understand that you think it to be messy.

We can make it much simpler knowing that, for an ideal (or almost ideal) gas, the enthalpy is very close to linearity with respect to $\tau$. So, using the rigorous formula compute $H$ at the lower bound you need and at the limit of the range of the correlation. For this case, this would lead to
$$\int_{0.50}^{0.65} C_p^0\,d\tau=4.49551\qquad \text{and} \qquad \int_{0.50}^{2.00} C_p^0\,d\tau=50.2249$$ Draw a straight line
$$H_{0.65}=A + 0.65\,B\qquad \text{and} \qquad H_{2.00}=A + 2.00\,B $$ giving
$$H(\tau)=-17.5224+33.8737\,\tau$$ So, for $H=34.567$, $\tau_0=1.53775$.

This is less accurate but Newton method will work like a charm as shwon below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \tau_n \\
 0 & 1.53775000000 \\
 1 & 1.68796886170 \\
 2 & 1.68711267745 \\
 3 & 1.68711265309
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. So the step size 0.01 gets it really close to  integral result. Do I understand it right?

Comment: @UpickyRizek. Yes, you did ! Again, you did not use the correct bounds. The first line of my results correspond to $\Delta t=1$

Comment: would you know the way calculate T2 if I have a result of the integral?

Comment: Thank you, Claude, I will certainly try all approaches and the linear could be the best one as I am looking to calculate in ranges between 20°C and 1000°C

Comment: @UpickyRizek. You are welcome ! I agree : the linear approach for $H$ is the best since, using Newton, we just need a "reasonable" estimate and since $H$ is "almost" linear with $\tau$, it will be a piece of cake. Cheers :-)